# Why must I reset ADB so frequently in Eclipse in order to connect to an Android device?

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

When developing an Android project in Eclipse, I frequently find that the android device is offline.  When I reset the Android Debug Bridge ([adb](/questions/tagged/adb)) the problem is resolved--albeit temporarily.  There are many answers on SE that suggest resetting ADB to resolve similar problems, but I haven't found an answer to the underlying cause:

- **What is happening that requires ADB to be reset so frequently?**

---

UPDATE: Here's some detail about my configuration to the extent it's relevant (per @Berdon's request):

- Development environment is running Windows 8.
- Eclipse JDT (3.8.1), Eclipse Platform (4.2.1), Eclipse RCP (4.2.1), ADT (21.0.1.201212060302).
- Connecting to Android Devices using a USB cable with no USB hub between them.
- The Android devices in question include primarily a Nexus 7 tablet and an HTC Thunderbolt, although I've seen it occur with other devices as well.

Comment: OS? Device? Are you using a USB hub in between the device and the dev box? Is it self powered or externally powered? There are a variety of variables at play here.

Comment: @Berdon added configuration details.  Are they relevant to what's happening?  I had the feeling this happened to everyone.

Comment: I remember having to do it with Windows 7; however, I've been using a mac as my primary dev box for the last year (OSX 10.7.5) and haven't had to since.

Comment: @Berdon Well don't get me wrong.  It works.  It's just an annoyance having to reset frequently.  I figure if I understood the root cause, maybe I could make some changes to speed up my dev time.

Comment: Sadly, I have to agree with @Berdon. Virtually no issues on Mac, and all sorts of issues on Windows. I would assume Linux acts the same as Mac. Interestingly, I had my dev environment (Win7) set up in VMWare on a Win7 host, and the virtual USB was a lot more reliable than a native connection. It's one of those things we just have to live with.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen similar problems when I'm working with Eclipse as well. But I believe it's a problem with Windows, not Android nor Eclipse.

I'll test this one once I'm back home:

1. Go to Control Panel -> System -> Device Manager
2. Open the Universal Serial Bus Controllers
3. Right Click all Root Hubs
4. In the Power Management tab de-select the box "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power"

I'm on a Windows 7 computer, so you'll have to access the Control Panel via 
<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>.

Comment: Going to give this a try when I get home as well.  In the meantime, +1 for having an approach.  TBD whether it's THE approach.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't cure it for me.  Did you get a chance to test it for you?

Comment: it seemed to do the trick for me. It might be different because of the OS.

Comment: +1'd it for a good theory, but going to leave the question open in case someone has any other ideas.